# Ti Sensor Tag Getting Started

Tags: android, sensors

The Ti Sensor tag is expected to unleash a bound of creativity in the Android - Sensor area.

Is there a minimal set of source code to help people get started. Just enough to get started.

Ti does supply the Source Code there are hundreds and hundreds of files to make a professional demo. This is no use to a beginner trying to figure out how to use this sensor with his android.

The software can be found at http://www.ti.com/tool/sensortag-sw#Technical Documents. You need to sign in to download and  execute an installer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find this example project quite useful:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sample.ble.sensortag&hl=en

Source code available here:
https://github.com/StevenRudenko/BleSensorTag

Answer (score 0):

The O'Reilly book *Getting Started with Bluetooth Low Energy* may be helpful.  It seems like TI has taken down the Android app in the link provided by user462990.